# Why does gfortran produce such a large stack size compared to C++ in this simple program?

Tags: assembly, fortran, gfortran

I've been compiling some simple programs into assembly from C++ and Fortran to try and get more of an appreciation for computer architecture. I've written a very simple program in both C++ and Fortran to produce some output and then return. What I don't understand is why the Fortran compiler (gfortran) would produce assembly that creates such a large stack frame compared to the C++.

f_subroutines.f

```
      PROGRAM F_SUBROUTINES
      CALL SAY_HELLO
      CALL SAY_GOODBYE

      END

      SUBROUTINE SAY_HELLO
        PRINT '(A6)', "Hello."
      END

      INTEGER*4 FUNCTION GET_MY_NUMBER()
        GET_MY_NUMBER = 3
      END

      SUBROUTINE SAY_GOODBYE
        INTEGER :: GET_MY_NUMBER
        PRINT '(A18, I1, A19)',
     1 "Here's my number: ", GET_MY_NUMBER(), ". Call me. Goodbye!"
      END
```

cpp_subroutines.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

void say_hello()
{
    std::printf("Hello.\n");
}

int get_my_number()
{
    return 3;
}

void say_goodbye()
{
    std::printf("Here's my number: %d. Call me. Goodbye!\n", get_my_number());
}

int main()
{
    say_hello();
    say_goodbye();
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CPPFLAGS=-O0
all: cpp_subroutines cpp_subroutines.s f_subroutines f_subroutines.s
cpp_subroutines: cpp_subroutines.o
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
cpp_subroutines.s:
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -S cpp_subroutines.cpp
f_subroutines: f_subroutines.o
    $(FC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
f_subroutines.s:
    $(FC) -S f_subroutines.f
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) cpp_subroutines cpp_subroutines.o cpp_subroutines.s \
          f_subroutines f_subroutines.o f_subroutines.s
```

cpp_subroutines.s: say_hello

```
_Z9say_hellov:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    puts
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

f_subroutines.s: say_hello

```
say_hello_:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $480, %rsp
    movq    $.LC0, -472(%rbp)
    movl    $8, -464(%rbp)
    movq    $.LC4, -408(%rbp)
    movl    $4, -400(%rbp)
    movl    $4096, -480(%rbp)
    movl    $6, -476(%rbp)
    leaq    -480(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _gfortran_st_write
    leaq    -480(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $6, %edx
    movl    $.LC5, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _gfortran_transfer_character_write
    leaq    -480(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _gfortran_st_write_done
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

I am using gfortran and gcc version 5.4.0.

I'm not quite sure what the Fortran assembly is doing here:

```
    subq    $480, %rsp
    movq    $.LC0, -472(%rbp)
    movl    $8, -464(%rbp)
    movq    $.LC4, -408(%rbp)
    movl    $4, -400(%rbp)
    movl    $4096, -480(%rbp)
    movl    $6, -476(%rbp)
    leaq    -480(%rbp), %rax
```

It seems to be using 480 bytes for this stack frame and putting

- The source file name (.LC0) 8 bytes from the bottom
- The value 13 16 bytes from the bottom
- The format specifier '(A6)' (.LC4) 64 bytes from the bottom
- The value 4 80 bytes from the bottom
- The value 4096 (page size?) at the bottom
- The value 6 4 bytes from the bottom.

I'm perfectly happy with the output of the C++ compilation but I would like to know why

- The Fortran compilation produces such a large stack frame.
- What the values $8, $4, $4096 and $6 are there for.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is happening here but there is probably an `st_parameter_dt` on the stack which is fairly massive

Comment: See also the comments in [transfer.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgfortran/io/transfer.c#L39).

Comment: Do not expect optimal code when you tell the compiler not to optimise your code.

Comment: Why do you require the explicit format in Fortran? You are adding unnecessary complexity. PRINT *, "Hello." is simpler and more like the C example. The change is not that big, but it removes a couple of lines.

Comment: Can you post valid Fortran that can actually be copy/pasted into a compiler?  I don't know enough Fortran to fix the `Error: Invalid character in name at (1)` on the `1 "Here's my number: ", ...` line.  I wanted to compile (on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/hSU0Or) with `gfortran -fverbose-asm` so GCC would put comments on the asm source lines.

Comment: @PeterCordes, if you add  `-ffixed-form` flag for gfortran, it compiles as is (on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/OYt7nc). Or alternatively, as a single line in free-format `PRINT '(A18, I1, A19)', "Here's my number: ", GET_MY_NUMBER(), ". Call me. Goodbye!"`, should also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long-standing issue in GFortran, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48419 for details.